# Why does Python's dict.keys() return a list and not a set?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I would've expected Python's keys method to return a set instead of a list.  Since it most closely resembles the kind of guarantees that keys of a hashmap would give.  Specifically, they are unique and not sorted, like a set.  However, this method returns a list:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.keys().__class__
<type 'list'>
```

Is this just a mistake in the Python API or is there some other reason I am missing?

Comment: This is no longer the case in Python 3. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

Answer (score 133, accepted):

One reason is that `dict.keys()` predates the introduction of sets into the language.

Note that the return type of `dict.keys()` has changed in Python 3: the function now returns a "set-like" [view](http://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) rather than a list.

> For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class `collections.abc.Set` are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).

Comment: And it's a view instead of a list/set/etc. because there's rarely a need to copy all keys.

Comment: and those views can be handled as a `set()` ! which allow `dict.keys() | set()` operations. Py3 rocks :)

Comment: If you are stuck with Py2, you can do the same by calling `dict.viewkeys()` and using it with set operations `|`, `&`...

Comment: Notice that with Python3 it is still not possible to do `set.union(dict.keys(), set())`. The method using `|` as stated by @yota works, however.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2, it's less efficient to construct a set than a list.

Don't want to make an assumption that the user of the return value will want to search within the result.   Iteration is also likely.

In python 3, it's no longer a list.   It's an ordered iterable because ordering is guaranteed.

Comment: This question is about Python 2. In Python 3, `d.keys()` doesn't return a list.

Comment: Both decent points though.