# Django app getting the error "TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Here is the views:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
  def list(self, request):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
  
  def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from rest_framework import routers

userl = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
userd = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')

urlpatterns = [
  path('users/', userl, name='user-list'),
  path('users/<int:pk>/', userd, name='user-detail'),
  path('register',RegisterUserAPIView.as_view()),
  path('login/', LoginAPIView.as_view()),
  path('logout', LogoutAPIView.as_view()),
  path('products', ProductsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),

]'login/', LoginAPIView.as_view()),
  path('logout', LogoutAPIView.as_view()),
  path('products', ProductsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),

]
```

Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\erkin2\venv\lib\site-packages\routers\router.py", line 27, in db_for_read
    return settings.DATABASES.keys()[0]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried using `keys()` but then it says:

> function has no attribute keys().

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: It seems that you missclicked and installed `routers` library and importing from it instead importing routes from your application

Comment: @sudden_appearance What do you mean? Did I install the wrong library? I just checked and there are no errors about importing

Comment: Your trace is throwing from `site-packages\routers` which seems to be [external library](https://pypi.org/project/routers/0.10.1/). Your code may look like `from routers import ...` or `import routers`. Please either inspect stacktrace frames yourself or update your post with more than 1 frame of stacktrace

Comment: Yeah I checked that too. The only errors I get are "function has no attribute 'keys'" and "TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently and perhaps counter-intuitively, the `keys()` method for dictionaries does not return a list of keys. Let's check:

```py
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

print(d.keys())
>>> dict_keys(['a', 'b'])

print(type(d.keys()))
>>> <class 'dict_keys'>

d.keys()[0]
>>> TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

This was not always so. In Python 2, the `keys()` method did return a list. See [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886129/why-does-pythons-dict-keys-return-a-list-and-not-a-set).

To get an actual list of the keys, you can call `list()` on the dictionary:

```py
print(list(d))
>>> ['a', 'b']
```

Then indexing works as expected:

```py
print(list(d)[0])
>>> a
```

So you may want to change the line `return settings.DATABASES.keys()[0]` to this:

```py
return list(settings.DATABASES)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't know you had to call list(). It's fixed now, have a nice day!